# Missing call summary in Samsung Galaxy Apollo (i5801)

Tags: calls, samsung-galaxy-apollo

In my Samsung Galaxy i5801 after I disconnect the call I used to get a call summary from my carrier. This hasn't worked for some time.  I contacted customer care and they say some settings in the phone are changed and probably they are right because when I use the sim on any other phone, it shows the call summary.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I would try a factory reset via `Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset`.  This will wipe your phone, so make sure to do a back up first if you need to (you can search this site for backup methods).

Comment: DONT WE HAVE ANY SETTINGS IN THE PHONE TO DO THAT....PROBABLY FACTORY RESET IS THE LAST RESORT

Comment: @pawan Turn off Caps Lock.

Comment: let me know the exact procedure to do that....wat does it mean to turn off caps lock and how is it related to call summary

Comment: [http://bash.org/?105199](http://bash.org/?105199)

Answer (score -1):

No need to factory reset your phone. Simply turn off mobile tracker, it will work.

Comment: What is "mobile tracker"?